# Symfony single_text date on a form. Format not following locale

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm struggling with several things relating to dates and times in forms.

I have a date on a form and I'm using the single_text widget.

My locale in parameters.yml is set to en_US.

config.yml has under framework:

default_locale:  %locale%

I expected it to accept mm/dd/yyyy but that produces "This value is not valid." when I try input 1/1/2012 on my form and submit. The only way I can get it to work is to set format => 'MM/dd/yyyy' in code in the options array when adding the widget.

I guess I've missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default format for the date form type is IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, which is a date format which depends on your locale, but which probably is different from what you expect. For en_US this format is MMM d, y, so it expects something like jan 01, 2012. If you want to use the MM/dd/yyyy format, just set format in the options array as you did.